# Get file type in BLOB Oracle

Tags: php, image, oracle, types, blob

I stored an image in BLOB Oracle column. When I try to read it, I found that some first character in BLOB string is my image type (such as PNG, but surrounded by many encrypted (or binary) character). It means I stored my image type also. So, how to detect it by PHP code ?

This is my some first BLOB string look like:

```
'�PNG
```

Comment: "It means I stored my image type also" --- uhm, no. It's a part of image data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [zerkms wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221149/get-file-type-in-blob-oracle#comment42921294_27221149), this is part of the file format header.  It provides meta data about the file so programs know how to work with it.

To get information about the stored image you can use [`getimagesizefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php).

This returns an array of information about the image.  For example, my mini-avatar image here on SO (as seen at the bottom of this answer), when saved as a text file and accessed like so:

```
print_r(getimagesizefromstring(file_get_contents('./image.txt')));
```

returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32
    [1] => 32
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="32" height="32"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

As you can see, the image type is available via the `[mime]` key.

Note that you'll need PHP >= 5.4 for this function (which shouldn't be a problem since < 5.4 is no longer supported).